# How to check for class of "this" element in jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am writing a code that allows a user to click inside a video and have it expand, then revert to its original size when the cursor leaves the video area. However, the videos on the right side of the page expand to the right. Thus they cause problems.
I'd like to write an if statement saying that if the videos have a certain class in HTML, then they should animate to the right to offset the expansion.
Any ideas on how I could do that?

```
    var k=false;
    $(".content video").click(function() {
        
        $(this).animate({
            width: "+=40%",
            height: "+=40%",
        });
        
    });
```

Comment: Something like this - > `if($(this).attr('id')=='something'){..`

Comment: @Swati - Or even just `if (this.id === "something")`.

Comment: You said ID in your title, but your question mentions class. Which is it?